# expandable row groupings in KQL table

Tags: azure, kql

I have data in a table that I am displaying using KQL.

Once I've generated my columns I can then see the data in a table on my dashboard; and on the right-hand side there's a "columns" menu button, where you can apply row groupings.

Is there some KQL query that can automatically apply those row groupings? Currently I have to re-apply them every time I load the dashboard.

I know about the `summarize` command, but that loses the ability to expand out the data and see what's in the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KQL queries return tabular data, so records can't be grouped. The feature you're referring to (grouping records by a value in a certain column) is a Client feature, and is not part of the Kusto Query Language.